# Using the nul character in sed instead of "/"

Tags: bash, sed

I want to remove a line in a file containing a path. The path which should be removed is stored in a variable in a bash script.

Somewhere I read that filenames are allowed to contain any characters except "/" and "\0" on *nix systems.
Since I can't use "/" for this purpose (I have paths) I wanted to use the nul character.

What I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

var_that_contains_path="/path/to/file.ext"

sed "\\\0$var_that_contains_path"\\0d file.txt > file1.txt #not working
sed "\\0$var_that_contains_path"\0d file.txt > file1.txt #not working
```

How can I make this work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be using the wrong tool for the job here. Just use grep:

```
$ cat file
blah /path/to/file.ext more
some other text
$ var='/path/to/file.ext'
$ grep -vF "$var" file
some other text
```

As you can see, the line containing the path in the variable is not present in the output.

The `-v` switch means that grep does an inverse match, so that only lines that *don't* match the pattern are printed. The `-F` switch means that grep searches for fixed strings, rather than regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Since the filename can contain at least a dozen different characters which have special meaning for sed (`.`, `^`, `[`, just to name a few), the right way to do this is to escape them all in the search string:

[Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern)

So for the search pattern (in this case: the path), you need the following expression:

```
the_path=$(sed -e 's/[]\/$*.^|[]/\\&/g' <<< "$the_path")
```